# For the French Army under Jean Martinet (d1672) how and why were cavalry used instead of infantry?

Tags: military, europe, france, early-modern, cavalry

For France's army of the period of Jean Martinet (d1672) in the Early modern, how and why were cavalry used instead of infantry?

In European warfare the default company is the infantry company. This may be of varying grades of weight from royal guards through militia. But regardless of grade the infantry face the campaign and engagement in a common form. ^1^

In contrast cavalry squadrons face the strategy of campaign and the tactics of engagement quite differently from infantry. ^1^

How and why were cavalry employed differently to infantry?

The ideal answer will cover differential strategic mobility, independent march columns, screening scouting and anti-civilian actions; social policing and class; tactical mobility, manoeuvre, shock, lance armour and sword; and, cost of mobilisation, training and deployment.

^1^ with the exception of the dragoons

Comment: I’ve previously read extensively in this field and know the answer. It is being asked because we’ve had this question circled repeatedly and because Wikipedia and quora are rather bad at explaining principles of historical military science.

Comment: Effective infantry requires regular training, discipline, etc which is hard to do if the army is mostly comming from peasants. The professional part of medieval armies were the nobility, who preferred to fight in heavy cavalry, not on the foot, while the lightly trained soldiers could be still useful in infantry, This changed with times when professional soldiers, mercenaries, became common, and they formed very effective heavy foot soldiers troops.

Comment: I don’t see how the medieval is relevant to the early modern. Consider Martinet.

Comment: This seems awfully broad to me, covering early modern European warfare, and looking at differences in over a dozen things.

Comment: It is acceptable, and even encouraged, to [answer your own question](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if you know the answer and want to share that knowledge,

Comment: @sempaiscuba In this case I'm looking for the assistance of people such as David in refining the question; and, giving others the decent chance to answer prior to me.  While this is a gardening exercise to fill a hole in our resource, I strongly value other's answers and want to give a reasonable go to them first.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Covering just a few of the aspects named, for one specific country, could easily result in a lengthy answer.

Comment: @andejons specified to the big blue blob of Martinet.

Comment: Retracted the close vote. I'm not sure if an answer could realistically cover everything listed, but it should at least be able to handle most of it.

Comment: Because they dressed fancier. This is the guy who gave us the word [martinet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/martinet), after all. :D